Why is the player shooting in the wrong direction? (auto lock-on)
I've been following this Godot tutorial on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwCiGixlqiU , but I'm having issues with the gun shooting in the wrong direction. I believe I've done everything correctly, but I'm still encountering problems. Can anyone help me figure out if I made a mistake or if this is an issue with Godot?
# Bullet script
extends Area2D

const SPEED = 1000
const RANGE = 1200

var travelled_distance = 0
var direction = Vector2.RIGHT.rotated(rotation)

func _physics_process(delta):
    var movement = direction * SPEED * delta
    position += movement
    travelled_distance += movement.length()
    
    if travelled_distance > RANGE:
        queue_free()
        
func _on_body_entered(body):
    queue_free()
    if body.has_method("take_damage"):
        body.take_damage()

# Shooter script
extends Area2D

func _physics_process(delta):
    var enemies_in_range = get_overlapping_bodies()
    if enemies_in_range.size() > 0:
        var target_enemy = enemies_in_range.front()
        look_at(target_enemy.global_position)

func shoot():
    const BULLET = preload("res://scnes/bullet.tscn")
    var new_bullet = BULLET.instantiate()
    
    new_bullet.global_rotation = $Point.global_rotation
    new_bullet.global_position = $Point.global_position
    $Point.add_child(new_bullet)

func _on_timer_timeout():
    shoot()

The bullet seems to be shooting in an unexpected direction.
I ensured that the direction is set correctly by rotating Vector2.RIGHT with the bullet's rotation.
The shooting logic is supposed to instantiate a bullet at the correct position and rotation of the Point node.
What could be causing the bullet to shoot in the wrong direction?

The code looks fine. Your problem is probably with your setup.
Potentially some sprite is misaligned. Or it could be to do with the fact that bullet is made relative to Point. It might need detaching.
